# Summation $ \sum_{k=-\infty}^n a^k$

Tags: summation

Is there any formula that directly gives the result of
this summation:
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^n a^k$$
?

Comment: its a geometric series plus a finite sum. the result is finite for $|a|>1$.

Comment: If $|a| > 1$:
$$\dfrac{a^{n+1}}{a - 1}$$

Comment: You should show your work when you ask a question.

Comment: i searched the internet but i couldn't find any close answer.

Comment: Searching for an answer on the Internet is not "your work."

Comment: @Max More concisely it's just a geometric series. (With first term $a^n$ and ratio $a^{-1}$.)

Comment: @arctictern both is correct and leads to the same result, its a matter of taste. i didn't want to make it too complicated since ppl who start getting in contact with math are often not so familar with index changes, splitting a sum into 2 sums is mostly easier to understand.

Comment: I saw exactly this question on this site several days ago. Can't find it now. Where does the problem come from?

Comment: it is in the book of discrete time signal processing written by alan v. oppenheim, question 2.10 a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may write
$$
\sum_{-\infty}^na^k=\sum_{-\infty}^0 a^k+\sum_1^n a^k
$$ then one may use the standard geometric series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \,\, x\neq1,\quad \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x},\quad |x|<1.
$$
Finally the sought sum is

> $$
> \sum_{-\infty}^na^k=\sum_0^{\infty} a^{-k}+\sum_1^n a^k=\frac{1}{1-\frac1a}+\frac{a(1-a^{n})}{1-a}=\frac{a^{n+1}}{a-1},\quad |a|>1.
> $$

Comment: If one divides out $a^{n}$ and rewrites the sum as $a^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^{-k}$ then the geometric series is directly applicable (no splitting needed).

Comment: @Semiclassical Good catch!

Comment: @Semiclassical Another short way: $\sum_{k=-n}^\infty a^{-k}$ (no need to factor out $a^n$)

Comment: My preferred way (which is quite similar to Yves's answer): $$(a-1)\sum_{k=-\infty}^n a^k=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n+1} a^k-\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n} a^k=a^{n+1}\implies \sum_{k=-\infty}^n a^k=\frac{a^{n+1}}{a-1}$$

Comment: Yes, but you are proving the formula... Not just applying. But since it is a short proof, I understand your point of view.

Answer (score 2):

$$
S_{n+1}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n+1} a^k=S_n+a^{n+1}$$
and

$$S_{n+1}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^n a^{k+1}=aS_n$$ give

$$S_n=\frac{a^{n+1}}{a-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: separate the sum, from $-\infty$ to $0$, and from $0$ to $n$. Make the change of variables $k\mapsto -k$ in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Another aspect to view this from is convolution/deconvolution pair of a discretized differential operator $[-1,1]$ has $\mathcal{Z}$ transform $a-1$. And the integral filter which is $[\cdots,1,0,\cdots]$ would have the given series as it's $\mathcal{Z}$-transform (here $n$ is the position of the last 1). The integral of the derivative is the identity [1] and as composition corresponds to multiplication in the $\mathcal{Z}$ domain we have our correspondence between the three of them.

We can check by a discrete approximation of the convolution in matlab or octave:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]; b = [0,-1,1];
conv(a',b','valid')'
ans =
0   0   0   1   0   0
```

a is the integral of the first four values, b is a differential approximation. In theory a would be of infinite length of 1s from $-\infty$ up to position $n$.

Comment: Erm. It may only be me, but regardless of whether it being correct, this answer makes me orders of magnitude more confused about the question than I was before reading it.

Comment: That depends solely on the reader. I can't know the background of everyone who reads questions and answers. One answer can confuse one reader but may help another.

Comment: Well, admittedly. But from your answer: where does $n$ come up in what you write, for instance? (To ask for a specific point.) (Also, sorry for the grammatical mistake I made above.)

Comment: Tried making it a bit more clear with an example in matlab. $n$ is the position of the last $1$ in the integral filter.